# How to store a picture using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

How to store a picture using Entity Framework?

Comment: Serialize it to byte array and save in DB

Comment: Use a [varbinary] column in DB table and store the bytes of the image. Other option would be to convert image data to Base64 and store in DB table as varchar(MAX) and use the Base64 itself in the html

Comment: Save those pictures somewhere else then record the paths in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options come to my mind:

1. Use a [varbinary] column in DB table and store the bytes of the image.
2. Convert image data to Base64 and store in DB table as varchar(MAX). This way you can use the Base64 string in the html "img" tag directly
3. Rather than storing static files in DB - why not store the images in a directory that your web server can serve. And store the Path to the image in the Database. In the html set the "img" tag src to the path